# Gulp-sprite-glue glue is not defined

Tags: ubuntu, gulp, zsh, linux-mint, zshrc

I have OS Linux Mint 17.2 cinnamon and i'm using ZSH.
After installing Gulp and plugin gulp-sprite-glue, when i run it, i got error:

`ReferenceError: glue is not defined`

But when i'm typing **glue -v** i'm getting **glue 0.11.1**

As i understand, glue is installed, and the problem is, that the glue is not added to **$PATH variable** in **.zshrc** .

After typing command  **where glue**, i get this **/usr/local/bin/glue**
and after that i open .zshrc file and add this: **PATH=/usr/local/bin/glue** and nothing happened.

Thank's for any advice.

Comment: Probably not related to the shell. Also, your path should include the directory that contains the executable, not the executable path itself.

Comment: Thank's for help, but you can pls show an example of this ?

Comment: Of how to add example